# protective border around a grave

Tags: sharia, grave

Assalamu Alaykom,

Is it permissible to erect a wooden border of one hand span in height around an individual grave for the purpose of protecting it from being stepped on?

The context is this grave is located within a cemetery that has secure fencing around the entire graveyard. However the individual graves are within close proximity of each other. There is a small concrete footpath between each grave however there is a concern that when there are active burials with large gatherings then people may accidentally step on the neighboring grave.

The intention of the border would not be for beautification purposes.

From Islamic sources it's clear to me that building structures over a grave is forbidden and the height of the grave should not exceed one hand span but I am unsure if building a border around the grave would violate this ruling?

Jazakallahu Khairan